# Как поставить yii2 проект на удаленный сервер?

Tags: yii2

Есть следующая проблема: сделал небольшой проект на yii2(basic) на OpenServer на своем компьютере(windows), всё отлично работает. Перекидываю по ssh на выделенный удаленный сервер(не мой) - не работает. Как правильно переносить и настраивать проект?
При попытках обратиться к страницам либо показывает кривой html код без стилей, либо ничего, либо ошибку 500. При ошибке 500 такие вот php ошибки в логе:

```
"PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'app\assets\AppAsset' not found in 
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'yii\helpers\Html' not found in
```

и т.п. 
Удаленный сервер:
Linux vm357004.had.su 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u1 (2018-08-03) x86_64

Настройки OpenServer:

- Apache - PHP-7+Nginx-1,12
- PHP 7.2
- Mysql 5,5 (хотя эта информация не меняет сути дела, БД пока не переносил, т.к. даже страницы обычный открыть нормально не могу)

Настройки сервера сам не знаю, они чуть ниже, возможно, но актуальны, по крайней мере, запуститься должно было.
Я переносил так: подключился по ssh в phpstorm, сделал upload на сервер, открыл в браузере web папку, там были ошибки с доступом, я разрешил доступ ко всем папкам и файлам yii2, ошибка пропала, я запустил еще раз, ничего не произошло, начал запускать другие папки из views, там либо отображается криво без стилей, либо 500 ошибка и ошибки в логах, которые я писал выше.
Пытался сделать тоже самое по ftp, тоже самое.
Создал в public_html папку admin на сервере и кидаю все файлы из папки проекта basic с компьютера в папку admin. 
Мне бы хотя бы общий гайд, как вообще переносить в таком случае проект.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Уже не знаю, что еще делать.

Comment: Добавьте конкретики.Что значит удаленный компьютер? Какие настройки OpenSrver используете? Какие версии? Какие на удаленке? Покажите дерево файлов... как запускаете...

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Добавил всё, что смог

Comment: Т к у вас был на локалке, посмотрите временные настройки, касающиеся локалки. Например файлы htaccess, может где то путями написаны

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц А если я пытаюсь даже напрямую открывать файл по всему его адресу, но все равно тоже самое?

Comment: Вы говорили у вас как то открывалось, только без стилей. Откройте так же,  и посмотрите причину почему не подгружаются стили

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Оно через раз по разному открывается: то никак, то без стилей, то с ошибкой php, указанной в вопросе. Кстати, только что через композер поставил чистый проект yii2 basic, прекрасно работает

Comment: Значит в проекте прописано что то не так...например настройки

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Вроде настроил кое-как, перекидав в пустой проект свои файлы, но теперь у меня при авторизации браузер пишет, что слишком много раз была выполнена переадресация. То одно, то другое, нет покоя)

Comment: Мне кажется это настройки самого сервера

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц А как настройки сервера мешают увидеть AppAsset?